# How to create and run animation for RadSlideView item in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I have an image in Telerik slideView control and a Button on the AppBar. When AppBar Button is tapped  I change image source of the active Image. Everything works well  but I need an Animation for changing image source. I'm using MVVMlight. Coul anybody help me with animation image appearance by tap on appBar button. Any information would be useful.

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView 
   x:Name="slideView" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Covers}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCover ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
ItemRealizationMode="ViewportItem" >
<telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Image x:Name="DisplayImage" Source="{Binding FullCover}">/Image>                               
    </DataTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to implement?